# ArgumentOutOfRangeException. But it should not be there

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

So I have and method like this.

```
var someColletion = _someService.GetSomeCollection(someParam);

var taskCollection = new Task<double>[someCollection.Count];

for (int i = 0; i < taskCollection.Length; i++)
{
    // do some stuff on the i-th element of someCollection and taskCollection 
    // and start the i-th task
}

Task.WaitAll(taskCollection);

double total = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < taskCollection.Length; i++)
{
    // get the result of each task and sum it in total variable
}

return total;
```

the case is when it comes into first for loop and the number of elements in both collections are suppose 1 the `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` is being thrown and then AggregateException is being thrown on `Task.WaitAll()` because the `i` becomes 1 (I don't know why but it does) and when it tries to access the i-th (second) element in array that contains just one element, this happens. But there is more to this. If i set a break point before first loop and go step by step then this thing does not happen. when `i` becomes one the cycle ends. and everything's okay. now the method I provided above is called by an ASP.NET MVC Controller's Action which itself is called Asynchronously (by ajax call) suppose 3 times. and out of this three just one executes correctly other two do the thing I said above (if not breakpointed). I think that this problem is caused by ajax call most probably because when I breakpoint it stops other calls from executing. Can anyone suggest anything ?

Comment: You're declaring someColletion -- a typo.

Change to:

var someCollection = _someService.GetSomeCollection(someParam);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I *suspect* you're using `i` within the first loop, capturing it with a lambda expression or anonymous method, like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < taskCollection.Length; i++)
{
    taskCollection[i] = Task.Run(() => Console.WriteLine(i));
}
```

If that's the case, it's the *variable* `i` which is being captured - not the value of the variable for that iteration of the loop. So by the time the task actually executes, it's likely that the value of `i` has changed. The solution is to take a *copy* of the iteration variable within the loop, in a separate "new" variable, and capture that in the anonymous function instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < taskCollection.Length; i++)
{
    int copy = i;
    taskCollection[i] = Task.Run(() => Console.WriteLine(copy));
}
```

That way, each task captures a separate variable, whose value never changes.

Comment: But I don't quit grasp why would not the value of the copy variable change with the i. Should not it be the same as i at the time task actually executes? Can you explain it in more details.

Comment: @Dima: No, it shouldn't - because it's the *variable* which is captured. Any changes you make to a captured variable are seen throughout the code using that variable, whether that's within the anonymous function or outside it. See http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter5/Closures.aspx for a bit more information (or read C# in Depth chapter 5 itself).